While working on gazebo, the sensor plugins are not showing despite being attached
I am making a robot simulation on Ros2 humble using gazebo. After much effort in opening it, now the attached sensor (ultrasonic) are showing on the sidebar but not on the model itself. The model is also somehow now grey... (original model had green, grey and white). I am a newbie in RoS and most online tutorials do not work for me so far.
I tried : running a sensor plugin I added in the URDF File and I expected to see similar results as here
